# How to access session in different requests in laravel

Tags: laravel, session

I save session variable in one controller and am able to fetch that after saving it.

```
class OrderController extends Controller{

    public function order(){
        echo "<pre>";
        Session::put('shakir','shakir');
        //Session::get('shakir');
        print_r(Session::all());
        exit;
    }  
}
```

and the output is:

```
Array(
    [_token] => LaQpxgzrhg0PX4YyGWmOZZpv1j3Ofj8jmEVQwpgD
    [_previous] => Array(
            [url] => http://127.0.0.1:8000/search
        )
    [PHPDEBUGBAR_STACK_DATA] => Array
        ()
    [_flash] => Array(
            [old] => Array
                ()
            [new] => Array
                ()             
        )

       [shakir] => shakir
    )
```

But when I try to access the same session in another controller, the added session doesn't exist in it.

```
class SearchController extends Controller{

    public function search(){
        echo "<pre>";
        //Session::get('shakir');
        print_r(Session::all());
        exit;
    }  
}
```

and output is :

```
Array(
    [_token] => LaQpxgzrhg0PX4YyGWmOZZpv1j3Ofj8jmEVQwpgD
    [_previous] => Array(
            [url] => http://127.0.0.1:8000/search
        )
    [PHPDEBUGBAR_STACK_DATA] => Array
        ()
    [_flash] => Array(
            [old] => Array
                ()
            [new] => Array
                ()             
        )
)
```

Any idea what is the issue or where I am missing.

Thanks.

Comment: I had similar issue and had to check kernel for StartSession middleware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove exit after print_r. Problem is session doesn't stores if request breaks at `exit`